# I can't activate the license in unity hub

Tags: unity-game-engine

I reinstalled **windows 10**. I downloaded unity hub from the official site. Running unity hub I saw the error "**You have no valid license**".

There are 2 buttons "manage license" and "dismiss" on the error. I click on "manage license" and I get to the "License management" page in the Unity hub settings, I click on Activate new license "select" Unity personal "further on" I don’t use Unity in a professional capacity "and click" Done And a **new error** appears **failed to reach unity license server**, after that I return to the" License management "page in the settings Unity hub, and click on "**Manual activation**" further on "**Save license request**" And **nothing happens**. I tested everything!

1. Disabled the Windows firewall.
2. Disabled Windows antivirus.
3. Cleared the registry.

I have installed: Unity 2019.2.12f1 and Unity 2018.4.12f1.

Answer (score 4):

I had some similar problems and tried SO many things that seemed reasonable, but then after I lost my cool with it and started trying crazy things, I saw on a forum that disabling your ethernet driver can cause your projects not to open and it'll show up as a license error. I re-enabled my ethernet driver, and it worked! A horrible and crazy bug for sure, unity should be at least a little ashamed.

Also, I've seen a LOT of different solutions work for this kind of bug, so I do apologize if my solution isn't your solution, just felt compelled to mention it due to how much trouble the bug caused me.

And also this thread may be able to help too... https://forum.unity.com/threads/unity-hub-2-3-0-doesnt-load-my-project.840487/

Answer (score 3):

1. First close Unity Hub
2. Open terminal
3. sudo your unity hub path

in my case (sudo /Applications/Unity\ Hub.app/Contents/MacOS/Unity\ Hub
)

Press enter DONE!
Thanks mchairuln95 at [link](https://forum.unity.com/threads/there-was-a-problem-activating-a-new-personal-license-make-sure-you-are-logged-in-and-have-intern.1167806/)

Comment: On macOS 12.4, it works.

Comment: Windows doesn't 'sudo'.

Comment: For windows users Right click on Unity Hub -> Run as Administrator should work.

Answer (score 2):

Solutions is simple:

1. Sign in at **id.unity.com**.
2. Go to the **"My Seats"** tab.
3. Under the **"Activation"** box, you will see how many activations you have used and which machines they are currently assigned to.
4. Select the checkbox next to any activations you would like to remove, then select **'Remove selected activations'**. Alternatively, if you would like to remove all your activations on the serial, select 'Remove all my activations'
   The license is now free to be used on different machines.

Credits to Unity

Comment: Clicks on "My Seats":

"We're sorry, but something went wrong.
We've been notified about this issue and we'll take a look at it shortly."

Wow, this process is super-smooth.

Answer (score 2):

Tried everything you can find on Google, with no luck.
Here is how I make it work:

1. uninstall Unity Hub and all version of editor
2. download Unity 2017.4.40 installer from https://unity3d.com/get-unity/download/archive
3. install Unity 2017.4.40, login with your Unity ID, get the personal license. Open 2017.4.40 editor should be no problem.
4. install Unity 2021.2.8 from above archive, it complains about no found of Unity Hub. But it can still utilize the license from previous step. Open 2021.2.8 editor with new project should be OK.
5. reinstall Unity Hub, not it can see the license, login is also done by itself.

Update:
To make thing simpler, use a pre-UnityHub version of editor (for me it's Unity 2017.4.40) to update a PE license from the offical server. Then it will be seen/adopted by the new editor and UnityHub. You don't actually need to un/reinstall everything.

Comment: I'm on a Mac, and this worked for me, thanks!

Comment: No. WTF. Minutes ago I was still working on my project fine. I've been using my personal license for years. And now locked out of my project, no license, and you're telling me I'll have to uninstall and reinstall all the sht I have to maybe get it working again? Give me the guy who's responsible for this bug. I'll have a word with him lol

Answer (score 1):

If you have used Unity Personal, or a different Pro/Plus license key, in the past you need to update your Editor to input your new license details.

To do so, follow the steps below:

When inside the Editor,  click the 'Unity' button if you’re on a Mac machine or 'Help' if you are on a Windows machine. Click 'Manage License'

This will redirect you to The Hub to follow the Online Activation process as outlined above.

If you are in a secure network environment, or receive an error whilst activating, it may be due to a connectivity problem.
Please try manually activating, carefully following the steps outlined in our documentation [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ManualActivationGuide.html).

If this does not work for you, please send the details along with screenshots of any errors received to [Customer Service](https://support.unity3d.com/hc/en-us/requests/new).

Comment: None of that works and customer support isn't an actual answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Cannot activate License** with **Unity Hub 3.0.0.0-beta4** on macOS Big Sur.

I got the error cannot activate licence when I open Unity Hub. So I try a manual activation with menu "Activate with license request" like explain by this link  https://support.unity.com/hc/en-us/articles/4401914348436-How-can-I-manually-activate-my-license-inside-the-hub- when I select my ulf file and click on the button "Activate" I had message "Cannot save the file".

Correction:

1 - Get the right version of Unity Engine installed.

The alf license request file generate by default include version 2017.2.0 so I edit the file and replace by the right version in my case 2020.3.17f1 and I follow the standard process. The last step still failed with message "Cannot save the file".

2 - Activate Unity license in command line (via Terminal)

`/Applications/Unity/Hub/Editor/2020.3.17f1/Unity.app/Contents/MacOS/Unity -batchmode -manualLicenseFile Unity_v2020.x.ulf -logfile`

Now everything work properly, maybe a other alternative should be use the production Unity Hub.

Answer (score 1):

Correct solution (on all platforms).

Open Unity Hub (v 3.x.x) as an Administrator. The underlaying issue is that the app cannot deal with OS permission models correctly.

Windows -> right click "Open as Administrator". Make sure to reboot before you do that (just because all processes need to be killed, and it's too long to explain here how to find etc...)

Linux/Mac OS -> Run the executable with `sudo` like this:
`sudo /Applications/Unity\ Hub.app/Contents/MacOS/Unity\ Hub`

Licensing will probably work flawlessly then.

ps: It took me several hours of trying every tutorial, every strategy, looking for older Unity Hub versions; manual activation; NOTHING works, except this.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on windows try to see that RPC Endpoint Mapper (RpcEptMapper) Service is enabled and running, and if no - start it (use win+r services.msc) to locate it