# How to fix Unity hub not opening unity project when clicked?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I fix it before by uninstalling unity hub and editor and installing again, it last for 2 days and the problem starts to show again. Did anyone here know a permanent solution? I need to fix it by now because we have only limited time making games and Im just new to game dev thank you for the answers.

Btw. I use unity editor version 2020.3.33f1

Comment: I dont know if you call it fix , but I some how opened it by directing to the unity editor 2020. I thinks the problem is with the unity hub?

Comment: Now I cant open it again directly it say I need unity hub but when I use the hub the project wont open at all

Comment: What Unity hub version are you using?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 5):

There was some issue with my Unity License. It was about to expire and my project was not opening. I added the license again and it extended the expiration date and the project opened for me.

Answer (score 5):

None of these answers really explain how to identify the underlying issue when encountering these symptoms.

If you open your Task/Processes manager before you try to launch your Unity project from Unity Hub, you’ll notice that the a new Unity process actually starts before exiting a few seconds later.

So something should be logged within the Unity log file. To identify the actual issue, locate your Editor log file:

e.g. Windows: `%AppLocalData%\Unity\Editor\Editor.log`

In my case, the log message clearly shows here that the license has expired. For some reason, the licensing page of Unity Hub doesn’t reflect this information, it still showed another 10 days on the license’s validity!

Once I’d fixed the license issue, the problem was fixed.

Answer (score 3):

For me, it has something to do with the wifi network I am using. If I am connected to some of them I cannot open my project.
I think, but am not sure. If you do not allow Unityhub to use public or private networks it will not open your project because it can not check if your license is valid. If you for example allowed unityhub to only use private networks mybe try marking the network you are using as private. Or vice-versa.

```
On the right side of the taskbar, select the Wi-Fi network icon.
Under the name of the Wi-Fi network that you're connected to, select Properties.
Under Network profile, select Public or Private.
```

EDIT: Changing connection properties (private/public) did not work for me (read comment for details)

Comment: @Lunar When using my laptop: For me it just does not open any projects when I am on my home network. It does not matter if I am opening them directly by clicking the scene file or via Unity Hub. I have to connect to my mobile phone hot-spot (network). Only then I can open my projects. Have tried changing network properties (private/public) and it does not help.  But on my desktop PC, if I am connected to my home router via cable, it all works.

Comment: Only thing I am sure about is, that I cannot open my projects if Unity does not have an certain internet access.

Comment: I tried manual activation using this link https://support.unity.com/hc/en-us/articles/4401914348436-How-can-I-manually-activate-my-license-inside-the-hub- read from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/68999125/11232272. I knew that it was from my network because I'm in Iran :) and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem with Unit Hub on a MAC and it was not opening just hanging.

Worked out a solution for MAC:

1. Delete the folder "Unity" at *Library/Application Support/Unity*
2. Unity Hub will ask you to log into unity and confirm the license again
3. Confirm all details and it should work

Comment: Are you sure this answer adds something new vs the previous answers?

Comment: @picchiolu the directory he mentioned is inexistent, this answer should be taken down.

Comment: Unity started opening after doing that, but then shut down for no reason

Comment: I can confirm this solved the problem for me right now (June 2023)

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/baba-s/Unity-Hub-2.4.5 <---- Get

Use an older release, I don't think it's related to the internet connection or licensing at all. It's just that the latest release has multiple issues. The older release might give off nostalgia if you know what I mean.

Answer (score 2):

In my Mac, I do follow this, it should work

1. In Unity Hub > Preferences > Licenses > Return License
2. Add the License again.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using unity hub to open project , try sign in to your unity account from unity hub. That worked for me.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I wasn't able to open project, activate my license. So I just signed out from Unity hub and signed in again. Then, I added the license. Now I turned off the internet and started project, all went smooth.

Answer (score 2):

Turn off random hardware addresses its under your internet option. Just right click your internet in the bottom right to get to it. This worked for me idk why this option prevents you from opening a project but fine. If this doesn't work try to disconnect from the internet and then try to open it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using PlasticSCM as your source control, open the PlasticSCM application separately and make sure you are logged in.

Once I logged in with my PlasticSCM account, my Unity project opened successfully.

Comment: Thank you!!! I wasted 2 hours trying to find out what caused this. Just opened Plastic (seems I was already logged in?) before opening the project and that worked.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I just reactivate my license and everything works again.

Answer (score 1):

Deleting "C:/ProgramData/Unity" to force it refresh the license worked for me on Windows 11 as of July 2023 and Unity 2020.3.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem.
Try to download microsoft redist, especially if you just re-installed windows or similar thing. It helped to me.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist?view=msvc-170

Comment: specifically https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist?view=msvc-170#visual-studio-2010-vc-100-sp1-no-longer-supported worked for me

Answer (score 1):

I tried all the solutions listed here, and this is what ended up working.

I'm running the Unity Editor from an external drive and was experiencing this problem. In my case the Unity Hub had somehow created a zero byte clone of the external drive's root directory and was trying to launch the nonexistent Editor from that empty directory.

I removed the fake installation from the Hub and pointed it to the correct path.

The following error inside `info-log.json` was what pointed me to the solution in this case:

> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, access '/Volumes/.../Unity'

Answer (score 0):

Delete Unity Hub and open the project through Unity. Otherwise, if you are using crack, try to completely delete Unity Hub from the registry and then put it in the firewall.

Answer (score 0):

The work around I've found (because the issue seems to be something along the lines of what @jib fashr was saying) is to have your wifi on when you open Unity Hub to allow it to verify your licence, then turn it off when you create a new or open a project, then once finished you can turn on your wifi again.

Idk why it bugs out like that but that's what works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I turned **off** [Random Hardware Addresses](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/how-to-use-random-hardware-addresses-in-windows-ac58de34-35fc-31ff-c650-823fc48eb1bc) and finally Unity opened.

[Settings Image *(Language: Turkish)*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/efoxy.png)

Comment: Your answer would be better if you could post an English version of that settings popup.

Answer (score 0):

FIXED: i had the same issue. I went to C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\unityhub-updater and ran the installer from there. That reinstalled the unity hub and everything worked normally. All my projects were there as well. You may have to sign in again tho. hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I opened the "Unity.exe" from the Editor folder and there was a missing dll file (msvcr100.dll). So I downloaded "Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Service Pack 1" and now Unity Hub opens my projects.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed

Please Install package Visual C++ for Visual Studio 2013

https://www.microsoft.com/ru-ru/download/details.aspx?id=40784

Answer (score -1):

I'm facing the same issue  I just **disconnect my Wi-Fi then open my project** . After that connect to Wi-Fi again. It's working for me.

The problem started when I install unity 2021.3.10f1 up until then everything went smoothly.

Need permanent solution.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Fixed: I had the same issues with Unity Hub, but uninstalling it and then reinstalling it resolved the problem. So, I suggest you try uninstalling the Unity Hub and then reinstalling it. This worked for me.